# Ajuda com Ajax não envia dados pro banco

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Estou tentando enviar um formulário para meu banco de dados. o Ajax diz que o cadastro do usuário foi efetuado com sucesso porém quando eu vou olhar no banco de dados não tem nada lá.

Meu Formulário.

```
<form class="form3" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="ressult"></div>

    <p>Nome completo</p>
    <input type="text" name="Nome_us" placeholder="Nome completo *">

    <p>Nome de usuário</p>
    <input type="text" name="Nick_us" placeholder="Nick da conta *">

    <p>E-mail</p>
    <input type="text" name="Email_us" placeholder="Informe seu E-mail *">

    <p>Senha</p>
    <input type="password" name="Senha_us" placeholder="Informe a sua senha *">

    <input type="hidden" name="Imagem_us" value="/images-profile/Profile_img_00_TSN.png">
    <input type="submit" id="Bot_Cria_login" name="Cadastrar_us" value="Criar conta">
</form>
```

Meu ajax.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.form3').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var formDados = $('.form3');

            $.ajax({
                location:'/arquivos/conta_usuario.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:formDados,
                cache:false,
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                success:function(data){
                    $('#ressult').html(data);
                    alert('Cadastrado com sucesso!');
                },
                dataType:'html'
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Meu php pra onde quero enviar os dados que preenchi.

```
<?php
    require_once('conex.php');

    if(isset($_POST['Cadastrar_us'])){
        $Nome_user      = $_POST['Nome_us'];
        $Nick_user      = $_POST['Nick_us'];
        $Email_user = $_POST['Email_us'];
        $Senha_user = $_POST['Senha1_us'];
        $Imagem_user    = $_POST['Imagem_us'];

        if($Nome_user == ""){
            echo 'Preencha o campo Nome corretamente.';
        }
        else{
            $SQL_Cadastro = mysqli_query($conex,"INSERT INTO Usuarios_login_s_n (Nome_us_sn, Nick_us_sn, Email_us_sn, Senha_us_sn, Foto_us_sn) VALUES ('$Nome_user', '$Nick_user', '$Email_user', '$Senha_user', '$Imagem_user')");
        }
    }
    else{

    }
?>
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada na resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na linha abaixo, você está enviado o HTML do formulário , e não os dados:

```
var formDados = $('.form3');
```

Para armazenar os dados do formulário à variável, use o método `.serialize()`:

```
var formDados = $('.form3').serialize();
```

O `contentType` também está errado. Remova-o que será enviado do tipo padrão. Troque também o `location` do Ajax por `url`.

O fato de você estar recendo o alerta não quer dizer que os dados foram recebidos, apenas significa que algo está retornando sem dar erros.

Seu Ajax ficará assim:

```
$(function(){
  $('.form3').submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var formDados = $('.form3').serialize();

      $.ajax({
          url:'/arquivos/conta_usuario.php',
          type:'POST',
          data:formDados,
          cache:false,
          processData:false,
          success:function(data){
              alert('Cadastrado com sucesso!');
          },
          dataType:'html'
      });
      return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: E para complementar: O formulário não irá enviar o valor do botão "Cadastrar_us". No `php`, para verificar se há um `POST`, basta utilizar `if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ) { ... }`

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.